# How can I "force" a git rebase?

Tags: git, github

The current branch is `myBranch` and it is 2 commits behind master. I want to rebase it, so I tried

```
$ git rebase master

Current branch myBranch is up to date.


$ git push --set-upstream origin myBranch

Branch myBranch set up to track remote branch myBranch from origin.
Everything up-to-date
```

It seems everything I try, I get "it's up to date"

Anyone in this situation?

Comment: How do you determine that the branch is '2 commits behind master'. If the remote `master` branch contains more commits then look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828404/why-does-git-status-show-branch-is-up-to-date-when-changes-exist-upstream) for instructions on how to update your branch(es)

Comment: Are you *sure* it's behind?  What happens when you perform `git fetch`?

Comment: Sounds like `myBranch` is not behind `master`.

Try doing `git rev-parse master` and `git merge-base myBranch master`. If those two commands yield the same SHA-1, then `myBranch` is not behind `master`.

Comment: I see that the current branch is behind master on the site where I forked the repository. There is **Request to merge marian-ald:cabal into master (2 commits behind)**, where cabal is branch name.

Comment: I get the same SHA-1. It seems you are right. I'm wondering why on the web page where I see my branch it's 2 commit behind master. :( [link](https://gitlab.com/coala/package_manager/merge_requests/7)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git rebase origin/master`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14727904)

Comment: @plasmacel doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: Your answer is too short, suggesting a "maybe try this" solution, which  should be a comment. Otherwise please explain what did the OP do in a wrong way, and why is your solution works better than that, giving a more meaningful and informative context for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the" git remote -v"  And check the Origin . if this is not set, set the origin as master and rebase again

Comment: I get this at _git remote -v_:  **origin git@gitlab.com:marian-ald/package_manager.git (fetch)
    origin git@gitlab.com:marian-ald/package_manager.git (push)**

Comment: it seems from the above comments it is not a issue , so you got what you are looking for ? or still the question open?

Comment: This is a confusing answer because you can't set the `remote` `origin` to the `master` branch.