# How SourceTree know the real remote version?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

About the question: [Why does git status show branch is up-to-date when changes exist upstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828404/why-does-git-status-show-branch-is-up-to-date-when-changes-exist-upstream)

I realize that "git status" can not know the real remote latest version until "fetch".

But SourceTree sometimes know it, and show a number upon the "Pull" button.

How can it do that? By use "fetch"?

By the way, SourceTree use "fetch", why can it "**sometimes**" show the latest version?

Comment: `git ls-remote` tells what the refs are like in the remote repository without having to fetch them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source tree has a setting to run a `fetch` command in the background every X minutes.  That's how it'll know if there are upstream changes without requiring you to explicitly hit the fetch button:

[image]