# How to git init a remote branch instead of master

Tags: git, github

I was asked to copy my team's remote branch, called v8.1, to my local. I am to do a bug fix against this branch.

In Github, I went to Code, switched to v8.1 and copied the SSH command, running it in Terminal: git clone git@github.company.com:folderName/repoName.git

Later, I realized I had not copied Remote Branch v8.1. I had copied Master. In Terminal, "git branch" reveals only 1 branch: master Is there a way to do a "git checkout -b" from Remote v8.1?

I guess my mental model of Remote Branching is off. Please clarify.

I tried git init w SSH. I'm expecting a copy of Remote Branch as my own feature branch on local.

Comment: `git fetch origin && git checkout v8.1`

Comment: The `git fetch origin` part is otiose; `clone` was not a single-branch clone, so it already created remote tracking branches for all branches on the remote.

Answer (score 1):

> In Terminal, "git branch" reveals only 1 branch: master Is there a way to do a "git checkout -b" from Remote v8.1? I guess my mental model of Remote Branching is off.

No. Your mental model of *local* branching is off. You do have all the remote branches. But `git branch` lists only *local* branches, and you don't have any unless you make one (because local branches are ... wait for it ... local!) — except that `git clone` by default automatically makes just one local branch for you, based on the default branch at the remote which in this case was `master`.

So now just say `git switch v8.1` and you will get a new *local* branch based on the remote tracking branch `v8.1` (assuming that there is one, as you claim — you can check by saying `git branch --all` beforehand, and you probably should).

Comment: “because local branches are ... wait for it ... local!” This can be a bit confusing. The refs are there, called “remotes”, which are local but not  your local ones… they are the “remote-tracking” ones. :) I guess there’s a reason why the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828404/why-does-git-status-show-branch-is-up-to-date-when-changes-exist-upstream/27828516#27828516) have so many upvotes.

Comment: Well, I stand by the way I said it. Local branches are _purely_ local. Remote tracking branches are based on, and occasionally synchronized with, the remote. Anyway I've given the full story [here](https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/), I don't need to re-explain it every darned time.