# What is the difference between repository and branch in git?

Tags: git

Someone who is well versed in git could help me to understand the difference between repo and branch. I am recently introduced to git and having a bit hard time to understand them. I was told to clone a remote repo (e.g. foo) to my local box. Then create a local branch out of it. Work (update/create/delete files) on the branch and add/commit/push to the remote server (e.g. bitbucket). After 2nd set of eyes review the branch and says ok. Then it gets merged to development or master branch.

Then what role, a repository plays in this picture? To me all the operations I ran is against branch...

Comment: The repo contains multiple branches - as you said yourself, you *added* a branch to it

Comment: Not my downvote.  You can think about a repo as a place where remote branches live.  A local branch is where you do all your work, and local branches sync up with remote branches.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A *repository* is your whole project (directories and files) that you clone on your computer. A *branch* is a version of your repository, or in other words, an independent line of development.

A repository can contain multiple *branches*, which means there are multiple versions of the repository. The purpose of versioning your code after all, is that you can work on multiple aspects of your project at the same time - each of those evolving in different *branches*. Git uses the expression "working tree" (representing your workbench) alongside "branches".

Related: If you want to know more about the [local and remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16408300).

---

Concerning the way of dealing with branches in your initial question:

> Clone a remote repo (e.g. foo) to my local box. Then create a local branch out of it. Work (update/create/delete files) on the branch and add/commit/push to the remote server

This is a nice and clean way to work with git. I suggest you always proceed like this :

```
----A---B---C--     (REMOTE, master)

            |
            |       (Pull to local : `git pull origin master`)
            v

----A---B---C--     (LOCAL, master)
```

Then create a branch from your local master (`git checkout -b branch1`), work on it, commit your changes and push to remote :

```
----A---B---C------     (REMOTE, master)

----A---B---C---D--     (REMOTE, branch1)

               ^
               |
               |        (Push to remote : `git push origin branch1`)

----A---B---C------     (LOCAL, master)
             \
              D----     (LOCAL, branch1)
```

Then, when you're happy with your feature/fix/whatever, you can merge `branch1` into `master`.

Answer (score 7):

A repository contains all the information about your project, including a history of all the changes. Each change is entered into the repository in the form of a "commit".

In order to show the difference between branches and repositories I will describe the process you mentioned and point out along the way the branches and the repositories being used. This is not intended to be a git tutorial, just an example so we can talk about branches and repos.

Typically there exists a remote repository which users can get a copy of, and to which they can submit changes. No actual development work is done directly in the remote repo.

A user gets their first copy of a remote repository by cloning it. This will create a local repository on the users machine. The local repo is a complete copy of the remote repo.

A branch is simply a pointer to one of the commits in the repository.
In the simplest case, there is the default branch called "master", and master points to the most recent commit.
Each commit is identified by a number, which is a hash of the repo at that moment. For example in this case master might point to commit:

```
2d2cd6cf6f634e88ad19fa454fdcd2e1c26009c7
```

A developer can clone the remote repo, and checkout branch master.
Then create and checkout development branch, (e.g. featureX-dev).

```
git checkout -b featureX-Dev
```

At this point both branches (master and featureX-Dev) point to the same commit.
Make changes to your files.
Commit the changes to the local copy of branch featureX-dev.
Now, in your local repository, branch featureX-Dev points to a newer commit than master does.
Push branch featueX-dev to the remote repo so it can be reviewed.

```
git push -u origin featureX-dev
```

The -u is used the first time the branch is pushed to the remote to tell git you want to track this branch.

Other developers (who have already cloned the remote repo) can get branch featureX-dev from the remote repository by performing a pull.

After they review it and tell you it's ok, then you can merge branch featureX-dev with your copy of master in your local repo, and push master.

But wait! What if some other developer has already pushed their changes to the remote master?

You checkout master in your local repo

```
git checkout master
```

Then pull master from the remote

```
git pull origin master
```

You have the new changes that someone else made, and master points to their last commit.
Now you can merge your dev branch into the local copy of master

```
git merge featureX-dev
```

If no one has changed master there is no harm done. The merge will just add your commits to the master branch.
Resolve conflicts if any are created, and then push master back to the remote.

Comment: Randy Leberknight, Thank you for taking time to reply back to me. Your detailed reply surely solidify understanding of the process I've been learning. Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 4):

In Git, the repository refers to your entire project.  Within a single Git repository, you have at least one [branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-branch).  You can use `git branch newFeature` to create a new branch within your repository to track your changes to the changes to your code base that pertain to a particular new feature.

Anytime you clone a repository you are creating a copy of the project repository on your local machine.  In addition, you will also be able to `git pull` any new changes that other developers have pushed up to the public repository (learn more [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/git-clone) and [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-git)).