# Resource not found on classpath

Tags: java, classpath

I'm on a new branch of a git project on which I've made my own config file called `MY_NAME.conf` which is located in

> Users/myname/IdeasProject/projectName/src/main/resources/config.

However, I'm having some issues getting my branch to run. So, just to make sure things are smooth I set up a new environment and I've cloned into the master. This is all done at

> Users/myproject

However, now when I try to run the project I get a message

> java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath:
>   config/MY_NAME.conf

Why is it looking for this file at all? And even if it is, why is it not finding `MY_NAME.conf`?

Comment: Your application apparently loads properties or something else from this file, but you forgot to add it to your new git branch.

Comment: But, it should be cloning from master - not from my branch, no?

Comment: was it added to the master branch? BTW, this looks like a git question, not the java. at least add the 'git' tag.

Comment: No. It's not on the master.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that classpath doesnt include conf folder.

You can modify/set class path with: `set CLASSPATH=path1;path2`

Comment: I tried resetting the class path, but it still doesn't seem to do it. I'm not using Play...

Comment: But, the issue I don't understand is why this newly cloned file (cloned from master which doesn't have this conf file) is even looking for the conf file which is on the other branch. It shouldn't even know of its existence.

Comment: Ok so master version doesn't have conf file. Just to make sure we are on same page, is this the correct flow?- 1. Cloned master to local machine.       2. Made new branch B.      3. Added conf file to B.      Now master is looking for the conf file that was added to B?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. No clue why it's even looking for it.

Comment: That is odd, this SO post may help solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408300/what-are-the-differences-between-local-branch-local-tracking-branch-remote-bra

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the classpath through one of these recommended [techniques](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).  Without knowing the specifics of your runtime environment, there should be a mechanism provided to include src/main/resources in your java classpath.