# Does "-u" in "git push -u origin master" add a reference to a remote tracking branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I understand that the -u argument in `git push` associates a local branch with its corresponding remote branch so that `git pull` and `git push` can be used without additional arguments.

However, as this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018004/8278160) states:

```
 git push -u origin master
```

Is the same as:

```
 git push origin master; git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

As Casey Li states in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XogN0Q4sb9o), the format `origin/repo` is used to designate a *remote tracking branch*.

As such, does `git branch --set-upstream master origin/master` in the line above associate the local branch, `master`, with its corresponding remote *tracking* branch (origin/master), or to the remote branch directly?

Comment: *“… with its corresponding remote tracking branch (origin/master), or to the remote branch directly?”* Those sound like the same thing?

Comment: @Ryan This answer states otherwise (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408515/8278160), and is the main reason I'm confused.

Comment: It ssociates the local branch with both the remote tracking branch and the remote branch. For `git push`, the remote tracking branch and the remote branch are updated according to the local branch. For `git pull`, the remote tracking branch and the local branch are updated according to the remote branch. Note that the remote branch and the remote tracking branch for `git push` can be different from those for `git pull`. You can pull from repoA and push to repoB.

Comment: Note that `git push <remote> <name>` effectively expands to `git push <remote> <name>:<name>`. This asks the Git at `<remote>` to set its own `<name>` (expanded, if necessary, so that `git push <remote> newbr` winds up being like `git push <remote> <newbr>:refs/heads/<newbr>`). If that succeeds, it implies that `<name>` on the remote now maps to the corresponding hash ID, so now your own Git updates **or creates** the remote-tracking-branch, typically named `refs/remotes/<remote>/<name>`. Once `refs/remotes/<remote>/<name>` exists in your own repo, your Git can set it as the upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> associate the local branch, master, with its corresponding remote tracking branch (origin/master), or to the remote branch directly?

In a local repo, there is no remote branches, only remote tracking branches, which are local branches tracing (ie keeping a copy of the last known state of) remote branches fetched in the repo.

See more at "[Having a hard time understanding git-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1070496/6309)".