# What does "No remote for the current branch" mean?

Tags: git

What does "remote" mean here? What does "No remote for the current branch" mean?

I am trying to merge my changes to my code in Git and I get this
message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A merge between two local branches of your local repo should not require any "remote" (which is a reference to an upstream repo URL)

But: As mentioned in [`git merge` man page, section CONFIGURATION](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_configuration):

> If `merge` is called without any commit argument, merge the upstream branches configured for the current branch by using their last observed values stored in their remote-tracking branches.
>
> The values of the `branch.<current branch>.merge` that name the branches at the remote named by `branch.<current branch>.remote` are consulted, and then they are mapped via `remote.<remote>.fetch` to their corresponding remote-tracking branches, and the tips of these tracking branches are merged.

So, if you want to merge another local branch into your current checked out branch, don't just type `git merge` (which would trigger the `fatal: No remote for the current branch.` error message)

Type:

```
git merge anotherBranch
```

You will need to add a remote later if you want to push to an upstream repo.

See more with: "[Definition of “downstream” and “upstream”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)".

Answer (score 2):

**ONE:**

A **local branch** is a branch that only you (the local user) can see. It exists only on your local machine.

while

A **remote branch** is a branch on a remote location (in most cases origin). You can push the newly created local branch myNewBranch to origin. Now other users can track it.

[What are the differences between local branch, local tracking branch, remote branch and remote tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408300/what-are-the-differences-between-local-branch-local-tracking-branch-remote-bra/24785777)

**TWO:**

1. You have cloned a project and, somehow, the .git directory got deleted or corrupted. This leads Git to be unaware of your local history and will, therefore, cause it to throw this error when you try to push to or pull from the remote repository.
2. You have created a new repository, added a few commits to it, and now you are trying to pull from a remote repository that already has some commits of its own. Git will also throw the error in this case, since it has no idea how the two projects are related.

https://www.educative.io/edpresso/the-fatal-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-git-error

**THREE:**

A remote branch is a branch on a remote location (in most cases origin ) i.e your online repository.

Answer (score 1):

you should connect the remote respository from local,use the command "git remote add origin 'your remote address from github' "

Comment: I did it and vs code says "remote origin already exits". I could not sign in 'github pull requests'. Do you know how I do it on vs code?