# How are remote branch, remote tracking branch and local tracking branch set to correspond to each other?

Tags: git

In git,

- how are a remote branch and a remote tracking branch set to correspond to each other?
- how are a remote tracking branch and a local tracking branch set to correspond to each other?

Are they done during `git clone`?

Are they recorded as some configuration variables in some configuration files? Are they manually modifiable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between local branch, local tracking branch, remote branch and remote tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408300/what-are-the-differences-between-local-branch-local-tracking-branch-remote-bra)

Comment: I am asking about how they are set up and where they are recorded, not what they are.

Comment: @Tim The answers to that question cover all that.

Answer (score 2):

> how are a remote branch and a remote tracking branch set to correspond to each other?

Git stores remote tracking branches in the `remotes/` namespace; see `git branch -avv`. The names of remotes and the names of branches make git to remember what local ref corresponds to what remote branch. They are files in `.git/refs/remotes/` subdirectory. After `git gc/repack` they're packed inside `.git/objects/pack/`.

Git updates remote tracking branches when contacting the remote repository during such commands as `git fetch/pull/push/remote update`.

> how are a remote tracking branch and a local tracking branch set to correspond to each other?

Git remembers that correspondence in the local `.git/config`:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@server/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
```

Now git knows remote tracking branch `remotes/origin/master` corresponds to local branch `master`.

> Are they done during git clone?

Initially, yes.

> Are they recorded as some configuration variables in some configuration files?

Yes, in the local `.git/config`.

> Are they manually modifiable?

Mostly yes, though the amount of work could be high — you need to work in the directory `.git/refs/remotes/` and edit `.git/config`. And manual operations are impossible for packed references in `.git/objects/pack/`. So you better use `git` subcommands.