# Reset branch to HEAD via JGit

Tags: java, jgit

I need to run the command
`git reset --hard origin <branch-name>`
via JGit to reset corrupt local commits done by users, and I'm using following code:

```java
git.reset().setRef(<branch-name>).setMode(ResetCommand.ResetType.HARD).call()
```

but it doesn't overwrites local commits and pointing to current remote HEAD.
I have tried with `git.fetch()` and `git.pull()` previous to `git.reset()` but it doesn't work, is there another method I need to use?

Also, how to print result why it's failing, I see that `.call()` returns `Ref` but the `Ref` object doesn't have messages, only `ObjectId`.

Comment: What is your ´<branch-name>`? To reset the current HEAD to a remote branch, you need to pass the full name of that branch, e.g. `setRef('refs/remotes/origin/main')`.

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the full branch name refs/heads/testbranch. I'm able to clone, pull and push using the same branch name but not reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that `git reset --hard origin <branch-name>` is not a valid Git command. To reset the current HEAD to a **remote branch**, you need to specify the branch as `origin/<branch-name>`. This is a short form of `refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>`. Is it this what you mean?

If you are specifying `refs/heads/<branch-name>`, then you are referring to a **local branch**. See also [What are the differences between local branch, local tracking branch, remote branch and remote tracking branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16408300/2986905)

The equivalent JGit command is

```java
git.reset()
    .setRef("refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>")
    .setMode(ResetType.HARD)
    .call()
```

Call `fetch` or `pull` only if you want to include updates that took place in the remote repository. Note, that `pull` is just a composite command of `fetch`, followed by `rebase` or `merge` (depending on the configuration). It tries to rebase or merge the remote branch into the local branch (i.e. `refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>` into `refs/heads/<branch-name>`) and will fail with a dirty working directory. This is likely not what you want.

Comment: Yes, I did mean ```origin/<branch-name>```(incorrectly typed) but thank you for recommending ```refs/remotes/origin/<branch-name>``` that worked for me